# Cannot access "user_shape" before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg

```
user_shape = answers["pixel-image"];
console.log("User entered shape = [" + user_shape_type + "]");

let user_shape;

if (user_shape === "Square" || user_shape === "square") {
    user_shape = new Square();
    console.log("User selected Square shape");
}
```

heres my problem. Ive looked up stuff online i just cant wrap my head around whats wrong. on my command line, these are the lines that are the problem. more specifically, lines 1 and 2.

Im trying to make a svg logo maker and all my prompts work up until the creation of the shape. Ive been working at it for hours and we just cant figure it out.

Comment: What is the problem?  Have you the obvious of moving the `let` up before you actually set the value?